# Can't see script within the DOM and it fires twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am using a masonry type code to display Divs on my page, and using an API to get the data so everything is loaded via `html+=` into the DOM.

e.g. Each div is loaded like this

```
html += '<li><div class="classname>content';
html += '<div id="like'+image.article_id+'">';
html += '<a href="#" class="like" id="'+image.article_id+'">';
html += '<div class="bLike" title="Like this article"></div></a></div>';
html += '<div id="unlike'+image.article_id+'" style="display:none;">';
html += '<a href="#" class="unlike" id="'+image.article_id+'">';
html += '<div class="bUnlike" title="Unlike this article"></div></a></div>';
html += '</div></li>';
```

Now, I am using a like button within the results shown which uses ajax to update my database to allow the user to see what they have liked. Simple.

So, to get the ajax code into play I have to load it into the DOM which I do as below, I load this after the divs example shown above:

```
html += '<script type="text/javascript">';
     html += '$(function()';
     html += '{';
     html += '$(".like").click(function(){';
     html += 'var element = $(this);';
     html += 'var I = element.attr("id");';
     html += 'var info = \'wish_id=\' + I;';
     html += '$(\'#like\'+I).hide();';
     html += '$(\'#unlike\'+I).show();';
     html += '$.ajax({';
     html += 'type: "POST",';
     html += 'url: "/pages/includes/ajax/like.php",';
     html += 'data: info,';
     html += 'success: function(){';
     html += '}';
     html += '});';
     html += 'return false;';
     html += '});';
     html += '});';
 html += '</script>';
 html += '<script type="text/javascript" >';
     html += '$(function()';
     html += '{';
     html += '$(".unlike").click(function(){';
     html += 'var element = $(this);';
     html += 'var I = element.attr("id");';
     html += 'var info = \'wish_id=\' + I;';
     html += '$(\'#unlike\'+I).hide();';
     html += '$(\'#like\'+I).show();';
     html += '$.ajax({';
     html += 'type: "POST",';
     html += 'url: "/pages/includes/ajax/unlike.php",';
     html += 'data: info,';
     html += 'success: function(){';
     html += '}';
     html += '});';
     html += 'return false;';
     html += '});';
     html += '});';
 html += '</script>';
```

Now, when a user clicks like, or unlike, it fires twice, therefore hitting the DB twice and basically doubling the whole workload which is never good.

So, I'm thinking that maybe the script shown above has been loaded into the DOM twice. So I go to firefox firebug and look at the code loaded into the DOM. All the divs are there that I loaded using the same `html+=` but not the script above. I know its there as it works prefectly.

So why can I not see it, and why is it firing twice?

Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT:

This is the API which loads the page:

```
function loadData() {
  isLoading = true;
  $('#loaderCircle').show();

  $.ajax({
    url: apiURL, // fetches from MySQL
    dataType: 'json', // data type
    data: {page: page}, // page number so each request brings in next records
    success: onLoadData // loads the data which is looped and html+= as at top of post
  });
};
```

Comment: I don't know if we can help a lot if we don't know how the API works. A quickfix could be to use [namespaced events](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events) and unbind any existing ones: `$('.like').off('click.yourNS').on('click.yourNS', func....);`. But finding out what the actual problem is and fixing is of course much better.

Comment: @FelixKling Added API details, thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm surprised that this code even works. First of all, you should not append `<script>` tag ( you can just fire this JavaScript inside success handler ). Secondly you are wraping JS with `$(...)` which means that it will fire only on *ready* event which fires only once, i.e. by the time AJAX call returns it will probably fire, so this script will not be executed at all.

Comment: I dont know if your concept allows this but appending the additional functions by `$(document).on("click",".like",function() { ... }).on("click",".unlike",function() { ... });` would be much cleaner and should solve your issue.

Comment: @freakish thanks - completely rewritten it as you suggested and now all perfect, thanks mate. If you want to put it as an answer I'll gladly accept. Really new to JS so learning all the time, appreciated!

Comment: @freakish $(function(){}) will execute immediately if the dom is already ready, it's not a normal event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what you should do is simply fire JavaScript instead of adding `<script>` tag and remove `$(function(){...})` wrapping, because code inside will be executed only on *ready* event which fires only once, when DOM is ready.